# Slack API: How to add user avatars in message when they click a button?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I think there's something in block kit documentation I haven't read yet, but I'm curious how one could display user avatars in a block like shown in the sample image below? Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This template is literally available in **App Templates** of Block Kit Builder

> https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?template=1
>
> Search for **Poll** after opening app templates.

**For the avatar picture**, 
You need to use `https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info` to get image url.

**For formatting**, 
This is the block you are interested in:

```
{
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_1.png",
                    "alt_text": "Michael Scott"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_2.png",
                    "alt_text": "Dwight Schrute"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_3.png",
                    "alt_text": "Pam Beasely"
                },
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "3 votes"
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Screenshot**

[image]